# joy ride tour plugin in multiple pages using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have tried joyride js to create Website tours. But both of them works perfectly well for static page/ multiple static pages.

Comment: _But both of them works perfectly_ if that plugins work perfectly, which is the problem?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.